# Behavior of static object?

Tags: c#, static

consider below code

```
class Repository{
  public static Item i; //Item is a type (class)
  GetItem(){
    // initialize i if null. Read i from an xml file if the last write time of file is greater than last read time else return current i
    return i;
  }
  SaveItem(item){
    //save i;
    //write i to xml file
    i=item;
  }
}

class User{
  public static void Main(){
    Repository r = new Repository();
    r.GetItem().MakeChangesToItem(); //method inside item to make some changes
    r.SaveItem(r.GetItem());
  }
}
```

Is there any chance this code behaves sporadically. Apparently it does for me. Sometimes the changes are reflected in the static item sometime not. When i changed the Main method code to

```
Item i=new Repository().GetItem();
i.MakeChangesToItem();
r.SaveItem(i);
```

it works normally.
Has any one experienced this? Thanks

Comment: Is "Item" a struct or a class?

Comment: @GiladNaaman look at the comments in the code, it's a class

Comment: You should post real code. When you post made-up code like this we have to just give you the benefit of the doubt on the parts you skip. And if we give you the benefit of the doubt, your code will be perfect. For example we assume you typed variable names correctly, but maybe that's exactly your error. Also remember that `static` variables are essentially global variables, so `this.i` does not make sense.

Comment: the real code is little long so i posted this. will post the real code in some time. you are right about this.i just wanted to distinguish between the parameter and field.

Comment: @Sat: You don't have to post your actual production code. You just have to post *valid* code which demonstrates the potential problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet yeah i got that. will do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static means it is not tied to any instance, but is per-type instead. A common issue with static is threading. If you have multiple threads (for example, an ASP.NET or WCF application, or anything where you use threads/tasks/parallel yourself) then craziness can ensue as they all think they're talking about different things, overwriting the same field.

I would say static is very unsuitable for that field.

Comment: i dont understand the line "If you have multiple threads then craziness can ensue as they all think they're talking about different things, overwriting the same field". can you please explain thanks

Comment: @Sat what isn't clear? Different threads changing the same variable/object thinking they "own" it, with no Synchronization? Recipe for badness.

Comment: ok.pardon my ignorance but here the change and save are consecutive lines of the same method. can you explain how it may fail to work? just to add this code is from a asp.net mvc app if that would help. thanks

Comment: @Sat consecutive is a subjective thing when you have multiple threads. Reference swaps are thankfully atomic, but you could get very odd effects where a single thread sees some properties from an outgoing old object and sone properties from the new object

Answer (score 0):

In addition, static object is related to class type that was shared between a set of instances of closed type. So the static object will be behave differently in execution. By contrast, if your static object is immutable so that you don't need to care about this object where you use multithreads.